# ARKIT Xcode, Switching from target to full screen view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm building an app on XCODE working with AR.
It basically identify a target and let the correspondent video play; I would like to start the AR experience placing the video on the target plane and be able to switch to a full screen view (which is then no more linked to the target) trough a button or a switch when the video it's already playing.

This is the code for the AR part, which is working flawlessly; we have 4 separate targets and each one is linked to a different video.

```
  public func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    let node = SCNNode()
    
    // Show video overlaid 
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
        
        // Plane creation
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "01ADAMOTARGET" {
            // Set AVPlayer as the plane's texture and play
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.adamoquadVideoPlayer
            self.adamoquadVideoPlayer.play()
        } else {
            self.adamoquadVideoPlayer.pause()
        };  if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "02GIOSUETARGET" {
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.noeVideoPlayer
            self.noeVideoPlayer.play()
        } else {
            self.noeVideoPlayer.pause()
        };  if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "04CAINOTARGET" {
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.moseVideoPlayer
            self.moseVideoPlayer.play()
        } else {
            self.moseVideoPlayer.pause()
        }; if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "03GIUSEPPETARGET" {
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.giuseppeVideoPlayer
            self.giuseppeVideoPlayer.play()
        } else {
            self.giuseppeVideoPlayer.pause()
        
        }
        
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        
        // Plane rotation
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        
        // Plane node
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        
        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = (anchor as? ARImageAnchor) else { return }
        if imageAnchor.isTracked {
            self.adamoquadVideoPlayer.play()
        } else {
            self.adamoquadVideoPlayer.pause()
        }
        }
    }
    
    return node
```

I've also wrote the part for the full screen view and it's working but I don't really know how to put the two functions together, here's an example code for a single video. It pauses when it encounters another target and another video starts playing.

```
  if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "01ADAMOTARGET" {
             let layer = AVPlayerLayer (player: adamoVideoPlayer)
             layer.frame = view.bounds
             view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
            adamoVideoPlayer.play()
        } else {
            self.adamoVideoPlayer.pause()
```